# How do I determine the next state in ember-routemanager?

Tags: url-routing, ember.js

If I have a route manager with 3 states like this

```
App.routeManager = Ember.RouteManager.create({
rootElement: '#tabContent',
initialState: 'test1',

test1: Ember.ViewState.create({
    route: 'test1',
    view: Ember.View.extend({
        defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile('test1')
    })
}),

test2: Ember.ViewState.create({
    route: 'test2',
    view: Ember.View.extend({
        defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile('test2')
    })
}),

test3: Ember.ViewState.create({
    route: 'test3',
    enter: function (manager, transition) {
        var careView;
        require(['require', 'test3'], function (require) {
            test3View= require('test3');                 
        });
        this.set('view', test3View);
    },
    exit: function(){
        this._super();
    }
});
```

How do I determine what state it's going to next in the exit event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something along those line, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/zxLkt/:

```js
exit: function(manager, transition){
    var route = manager.get('location');
    var params = manager.get('params');
    var state = manager.getState(route, params);

    console.log(route, params, state);
}
```

---

What do you want to do with it? What is your intention of doing this?

Comment: i want to determine that next state so that i can load the appropriate resources using requireJS and set the view of that next state. however, what i'm finding is that after i set the view of the next state in the exit event of the current state, in the enter event of the next state the view is still undefined. any idea?